# Position fixed relative to fixed parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed positioned **DIV** called Lightbox. My problem is that the *close button* doesn't stay on the top right, when I scroll the content.

How can I achieve that the close button stays on the top right corner?

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dgw8tj5r/)

```css
.lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    z-index: 10000;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.item {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="close-btn">x</div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change position:fixed to .close-btn http://jsfiddle.net/dgw8tj5r/2/

Comment: Use position fixed for the `close-button`.

Comment: @SathishS Sorry, but the button should be on the top right of the **lightbox** div and not of the **html** element. Preferable is a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the item div scrollable instead of the lightbox, then the close button will stay absolutely positioned in the top right corner.

Here is the CSS that I changed:

```
.lightbox {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.close-btn {
    top: 5px;
    right: 20px;
}

.items { 
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto; 
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/dgw8tj5r/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a sticky button to your `lightBox` div by adjusting your HTML a bit and adding a container to your lightBox content:

```
<div class="lightbox">
    <div class="close-btn">x</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">Item</div>
            <div class="item">Item</div>
            <div class="item">Item</div>
            <div class="item">Item</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then instead of the `.lightbox` div, you add your width, height, overflow properties on this new `.container`.

```
.container{
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Now your `close-btn` will not be included in the scrolling part.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dgw8tj5r/6/)

EDIT: Benjamin's answer is a more efficient version since you actually already have a containing div: `.items`. You can use that instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Anshelin this is not fixing the issue I think. OP clearly wants a fixed position _inside_ her fixed element, which is harder but not impossible.

Comment: I see! I think this is what OP was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw light box with proper position.
   2.Add close button and container inside light box ans close button position where you need.
   3.Finally added items inside container.

thats it.

thanks.

Fixed here

```
<div class="lightbox"><div class="close-btn">x</div>
    <div class="lightboxdv">
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
        <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

.lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    z-index: 10000;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.lightboxdv{
    width: 560px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.item {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of explanation to your code, so other viewers can understand more easily how it works.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change `.close-btn` position to fixed.

```
.close-btn {
    position: fixed;
}
```

I hope it works!